# Displaying homepage on localhost REST+ JAVA

Tags: java, rest

I have written a REST+Tomcat+Jersey java application and the rest oft he paths from the homepage are working fine. However, the localhost:8080 always returns a 404 because there's no function which points to it. As in:

```
@Path("/")
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String homepage(){
    return "Homepage";
}
```

I have tried using "/" as the PATH but that doesnt seem to work. How do I proceed? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you deploy a WAR named `foo` to a Tomcat listening at `http://localhost:8080/`, the root of your WAR will be available at `http://localhost:8080/foo/`.

If your JAX-RS application is configured to use an additional path segment `bar`, the `homepage` resource will be available at `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar`.

Check the Jersey configuration in your application to get the value of `bar`, if there is any.

Answer (score 1):

Can you paste the url you visited?

It should be like `http://{hostname or ip}:{port if not 80}/{app context}/service/{and you path defined in your resource class}`.

And also, it seems 2 possiblilites might cause the issue:

1 No root path defined in class level. Generally I'll define a path in resource class for application to recognized the jersey resource, like

```
@Path("/my_resource")
public class MyResource{ ...
```

2 You didn't define the HTTP method:

```
@Path("/")
@GET
@Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public String homepage(){...
```

Also, there's some way to show wadl, you can google it if you really cannot find the service.

Hope it helps.